# Scheme-less database solution to work on one machine only?

Tags: python, linux, mongodb, database, nosql

I am looking for a scheme-less database to store roughly 10[TB] of data on disk, ideally, using a python client. The suggested solution should be free for commercial use, and have good performance for reads and writes.

The main goal here is to store time-series data, including more than billion records, accessed by `time stamp`.

Data would be stored in the following scheme:

**KEY** --> "FIELD_NAME.YYYYMMDD.HHMMSS"

**VALUE** --> [v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6]                (v1..v6 are just `floats`)

For instance, suppose that:

**FIELD_NAME** = "TOMATO"

**TIME_STAMP** = "20060316.184356"

**VALUES** = [72.34, -22.83, -0.938, 0.265, -2047.23]

I need to be able to retrieve **VALUE** (the entire array) given the combination of `FIELD_NAME` & `TIME_STAMP`.

The query **VALUES**["*TOMATO.20060316.184356*"] would return the vector [72.34, -22.83, -0.938, 0.265, -2047.23]. Reads of arrays should be as fast as possible.

Yet, I also need a way to store (in-place) a scalar value within an array . Suppose that I want to assign the 1st element of `TOMATO` on timestamp `2006/03/16.18:43:56` to be `500.867`. In such a case, I need to have a fast mechanism to do so -- something like:

**VALUES**["*TOMATO.20060316.184356*"][0] = 500.867  (this would update on disk)

Can something like `MangoDB` work? I will be using **just one machine** (no need for replication etc), running Linux.

**CLARIFICATION:** only *one machine* will be used to store the database. Yet, I need a solution that will allow *multiple machines* to connect to the **same database** and update/insert/read/write data to/from it.

Comment: Sorry poor description of your problem...10 TB of data means what exactly? Large files? Lots of rows? Requirements related to durability?...Take your time and provide exact facts what you really want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDB is likely a good choice related to performance, flexibility and usability (easy approachable). However large databases require careful planning - especially when it comes to aspects of backup and high-availability. Without further insight about project requirements there is little to say if one machine is enough or not (look at replica sets and sharding if you need options scale).

Update: based on your new information - should be doable with MongoDB (test and evaluate it). Easiliy spoken: MongoDB can be the "MySQL" of the NoSQL databases....if you know about SQL databases then you should be able to work with MongoDB easily since it borrows a lot of ideas and concept from the SQL world. Looking at your data model...it's trivial and data can be easily retrieved and stored (not going into details)..I suggest download MongoDB and walking through the tutorial.

Comment: I need to clarify that only *one machine* will be used to store the database. Yet, I need a solution that will allow *multiple machines* to connect to the **same database** and update/insert/read/write data to/from it. So if machine `X` stores the database, I need to be able to have machines `Y`, `Z` access that database, change values in it etc; does `MangoDB` support this?

Comment: Why shouldn't that be possible? MongoDB is a typical client-server architecture...

Comment: perfect, thank you. I like the fexibility of `MangiDB`. Is there a forum where one can ask questions etc?

Comment: I assume you can read and the find the resources on mongodb.org *yourself*. Don't expect everything spoon-ready.

Answer (score 3):

A MongoDB instance can allow multiple machines to access it. You will, however, have to give the server special command line arguments in order to allow it to do so. You should search through the MongoDB documentation, it is pretty comprehensive. The documentation for mongodb's authentication model is [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication). It describes how to run Mongo in secure mode and how to restrict the ip ranges that can bind to it.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB will work. However looking at your requirement I will strongly recommend Redis.

Redis is a data structure store. Where you can store your arrays as values and access them with keys. It is easy to setup/use and is ridiculously  fast. It works well as one machine server and other way too.

There are excellent python client available for Redis such as [Redisco](https://github.com/iamteem/redisco#readme), [redis-natives-py](https://github.com/peta/redis-natives-py) and redis-wrap or simplest redis-py.

Comment: @Shekhar: thank you. A couple of questions: 
(1) how does `Redis` work when most of the data needs to be stored / updated on disk (I read it is mostly for in-memory operations, although this might have changed).
(2) will I have a performance penalty if I need to update an element (by index) of an array?  so say I need to update element `v3` in the array (using its position index). Will this be O(1)?

Comment: 1. Yes it persists your data. To be correct it writes to disk periodically (and this interval is configurable). 
2. O(1) see [LINSERT](http://redis.io/commands/linsert)

Comment: @Shekhar: thank you. It appears that unless you insert right at the beginning, it is still `O(N)` operation, which is OK. I am just curious, did you benchmark `Redis` performance vs. `MangoDB` before choosing `Redis`?

Comment: Given the specific requirement I think Redis would be faster. There are different benchmarks floating around if you search.

Comment: @Shekhar: thank you. Would `Redis` work in the same fashion, where one machine stored the DB, and multiple `clients` can connect to the data, modify it etc?

Comment: Yes, very much. That's true with MongoDB as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to consider is [Berkeley DB](http://bit.ly/hwYyw9) or [Berkeley DB Java Edition](http://bit.ly/gXs3rg). BDB is a C library, where as BDB JE is a Java Library. Both provide multiple APIs for storing data, including a key-value pair API (NoSQL), a Java Collections API and a Java Direct Persistence Layer (POJO-like) API.

Either library can certainly manage a 10TB repository on a single system. The both provide HA capabilities that allow you to replicate the database (and any changes) to multiple systems. Reads can be sent to the master or any of the replicas (providing load balancing). Updates have to be sent to the master. We have customers who use Berkeley DB in this kind of a setup today. Berkeley DB has been around for many years and this is exactly the kind of application that we do well.

Disclaimer: I'm the product manager for Berkeley DB, so I'm a little biased. :-)

Comment: thank you. Is `Berkeley DB` free for commercial use? (I am not talking about embedding it in a custom software -- I am talking abour simply installing it & using it on company servers for data storage / research purposes)

Comment: You can find the Berkeley DB license information here: http://bit.ly/g7h1mf. Basically, BDB is dual license, ala GPLv2. Under the open source license it can be used for free by open source projects. The commercial license is available for non-open source applications that are distributed to third parties, and for customers who want Oracle support.